# Parsing Error while adding fixed date column to dataframe

Tags: scala, apache-spark, databricks, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am reading table from Snowflake using snowflake connector and trying to add a fixed date column in databricks notebook. 
But i am getting error, I have tried changing format and date of the fixed date but its not working. Please find code and error below.

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.col
import org.apache.spark.sql.types.StringType
import org.apache.spark.sql.types.IntegerType
import org.apache.spark.sql.types.FloatType
import org.apache.spark.sql.types.TimestampType
import org.apache.spark.sql.types.DateType
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.lit
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
import org.apache.spark.sql.types._
import net.snowflake.spark.snowflake.Utils
import org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame
import spark.sqlContext.implicits._

// Snowflake Connection Function
    def createSnowflakeConnection(sfUrl:String, sfUser:String, sfPassword:String, sfDatabase:String, sfSchema:String, sfWarehouse:String): Map[String,String] = {
      // snowflake connection options
      val options = Map("sfUrl" -> sfUrl,
                        "sfUser" -> sfUser, //Snowflake user
                        "sfPassword" -> sfPassword, //Snowflake Password
                        "sfDatabase" -> sfDatabase, //Database
                        "sfSchema" -> sfSchema, //Schema
                        "sfWarehouse" -> sfWarehouse) //Warehouse
      return options
    }

    // Read Table from Snowflake function
    def readSnowflakeTable(format:String, connection:Map[String,String], table:String): DataFrame = {
      // Read the data written by the previous cell back.
      val dfT: DataFrame = spark.read
        .format(format)
        .options(connection)
        .option("dbtable", table)
        .load()
      return dfT
    }


    val SFconnection = createSnowflakeConnection(
                      "snowflakeAccount", //dummy
                      "user",
                      "pwd", //dummy
                      "DB", //dummy
                      "SCHEMA", //dummy
                      "Warehouse") //dummy

    val fixedDate = to_timestamp(lit("2019-09-23"), "yyyy-MM-dd")
    val table1 = readSnowflakeTable("snowflake", SFconnection, "table1")

    val df = table1.withColumn("fixedDate",fixedDate)

    display(df)
```

[image: error snapshot on calling display(df)]

Comment: does it also fail if you skip adding date column and run ```table1.show()```? the literal timestamp creation looks good, I'd expect a problem with the database schema

Comment: Can you give `table1.printSchema()` before adding fix date.

Comment: @Daniel it does not fail if i skip adding the fixed date column

Comment: @SMaZ sure, please find below

`table1.printSchema()`

`root`
` |-- "number": string (nullable = true)
 |-- "stDate": timestamp (nullable = true)
 |-- "qty": double (nullable = true)`